# I have an idea for a card game for couples. I want to go ahead and invest in it, where do I start?

Tags: game-design

From my end of the research I have checked that there are no similar games online. The idea occurred to me just a couple of days ago so I dont have much to grasp on. I know it will involve a detailed game play drafted out, rules, testing etc. but I dont want to just share my idea to the world as well. How do I start seeking (trusting) like minded people to make something happen. I am ready to put down some money if I get a good team going along with me!

My exposure to card/board games is that I play it frequently with my friends over weekends. Any resource would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: [Try here](http://www.jamesmathe.com) - good luck!

Comment: If you have the capital and the know how to market, avoiding outside investment is prudent for a variety of reasons.  In terms of developing the game, you could look to recruit a skilled designer, and offer them a cash stipend to make the development "work for hire", and incentivize them equity if the project moves forward.  (i.e. if they crack the formula for the game, you *definitely* want them as a partner!)  Use non-disclosure agreements, particularly for people not yet in the "circle of trust", to prevent the game design details from leaking.